# Преобразование Period.between в число дней

Tags: android, kotlin, дата

В результате вычисления Period.between ответ получается в формате `P26D`, `P1M` или `P2M14D`.

```kotlin
val dateFormatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy")
val d3parse = LocalDate.parse(d3, dateFormatter1)
val d4parse = LocalDate.parse(d4, dateFormatter1)
val d5razn = Period.between(d3parse, d4parse)
```

Нужно вычислить результат цифру дней (независимо дни или месяцы) и вывести (в дальнейшем этот результат будет прибавляться к другой дате).

Использовать такой способ не подходит, потому что нужно общее количество дней,
неверный результат — только дни выводятся, а не складываются с днями месяца:

```kotlin
d5razn.getMonths() + d5razn.getDays()).toString()
```

Comment: Что такое `d5razn`, откуда оно берется? [Отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1309136/edit) свой вопрос так, чтобы вашу проблему могли воспроизвести другие. Прочтите [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: отредактировал вопрос на предмет откуда берется d5razn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы вычислить количество дней между двумя датами, используйте `ChronoUnit` из пакета `java.time.temporal`:

```kotlin
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2)
```

Обратите внимание, что `ChronoUnit` доступен только для Android API 26 и выше. Для старых версий API используйте библиотеку [Joda-Time](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android):

```kotlin
Days.daysBetween(date1, date2).getDays()
```

Comment: импортировал `import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit` и сделал `val d5razn = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(d3parse, d4parse)`. Получил нужный результат в днях. Спасибо! Вопрос решен

Comment: спасибо за помощь! не знал что в котлине нет столько своих необходимых вещей

Comment: но что делать с этим - `ответ получается в формате P26D, P1M или P2M14D` - так и не понял

Comment: Просто используйте `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between` вместо `Period.between`.

Comment: `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between` возвращает результат в виде числа, как вам и нужно было.

Comment: Да, все отлично, прошу помочь разобраться с ещё вопросом - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1309352/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0