# Как создать для текстового поля маску ввода?

Tags: android, kotlin

Нужно, чтобы пользователь вводил в текстовое поле цифры даты в формате xx.xx.xxxx (то есть чтобы точки уже стояли и был возможен ввод только цифры).
Дополнительно чтобы была проверка на ввод даты - то есть что бы не вводили 32.03.2021, а также если год не високосный, то февраль могли бы ввести только  28.02.2011, а не 29.02.2011
Как это можно сделать?
(чтобы не использовать DataPicker)

Comment: В вопросе сосредоточено сразу несколько проблем. А вы сами уже пробовали код написать? С какой конкретной проблемой столкнулись, [отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1309352/edit) вопрос, приведите код.

Comment: На ваш вопрос в таком виде нельзя ответить объективно и однозначно. Можете посмотреть, например, [эти](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android) [библиотеки](https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/decoro), подойдут ли вам они?

Comment: подойдут, если их можно подключить, хотя там и нет даты, но думаю можно будет отредактировать код. В вкратце не подскажите как они подключаются ?

Comment: По библиотеке [decoro](https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/decoro) есть [статья](https://habr.com/ru/company/tinkoff/blog/312968/) на русском.

Comment: Почитал, технически хорошее решение, но тянуть библиотеку что стороннего сайта не буду.

Comment: Конкретизируйте вашу проблему, отредактируйте вопрос. С какой проблемой вы столкнулись? Вы хотите, чтобы за вас здесь написали код, тут таким [не занимаются](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Как минимум хотел бы узнать есть в котлин или андроиде возможность задать маски ввода стандартными средствами. И проверять корректность дат. Или придется использовать datapicker

Comment: Стандартных способов нет, поэтому и появляются подобные библиотеки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы проверить корректность введенной пользователем даты, можно написать такую функцию:

```kotlin
fun parseLocalDateOrNull(text: String, formatter: DateTimeFormatter) =
    try {
        LocalDate.parse(text, formatter)
    } catch (ex: DateTimeParseException) {
        null
    }
```

Как видно из названия, функция вернет дату либо `null`, если дата невалидная:

```kotlin
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu")
    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)
val date = parseLocalDateOrNull("31.02.1970", formatter)
if (date == null) {
    // введена некорректная дата 
}
```

Класс `LocalDate` доступен только для Android API 26 и выше. Для старых версий Андроида можно воспользоваться библиотекой [Joda-Time](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android).

Comment: `fun parseLocalDateOrNull(text...` и ` date = createLocalDateOrNull("...` опечатка? должно быть одинаковое название?  И как понимаю `"32.01.1970"` надо заменить своей переменной такого же формата? Потом дальше буду пробовать, пока ошибки

Comment: поправил опечатку

Comment: здесь мой код http://tpcg.io/s3uQKCIc, и я его не могу скрестить с вашим  ) потому что у меня и так стринговые переменные форматируются в даты

Comment: кстати андроид и так сам по себе проверяет даты, но слишком обще и просто. Например: `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '14.14.2017' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 14`. Но если пишешь 29.02.2021 - ошибки нет!, хотя в этом году в феврале было 28 дней. Да хоть 30 пиши ) Ошибка только на 32 возникает ) Поэтому нужен какой-то более продвинутый способ

Comment: Хорошее замечание, чтобы учитывались високосные года и отсутствие 31-го дня в месяце, необходимо включить строгий режим для форматтера: `ResolverStyle.STRICT`. В строгом режиме используйте [`uuuu`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41182911/1380933) вместо `yyyy` в паттерне. Ответ поправил.

Comment: только сейчас добрался до этой части кода, всё хорошо работает, спасибо! Если я хочу использовать этот код в версии Андроид ниже 8-й - мне нужно изменять код или достаточно подключить библиотеку Joda-Time ?

Answer (score 1):

К примеру ваш EditText

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/ac_registration_et_birth_date"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:hint="ДД.ММ.ГГГГ" />
```

Мы можем создать класс DateInputMask, который выполнит нашу задачу

```
class DateInputMask(private val input: EditText, private val saveDate: (dateTitle: String) -> Unit) : TextWatcher {

    private var current = ""
    private val ddmmyyyy = "DDMMYYYY"
    private val cal: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        if (s.toString() == current) {
            return
        }

        var clean = s.toString().replace("[^0-9]".toRegex(), "")
        val cleanC = current.replace("[^0-9]".toRegex(), "")
        val cl = clean.length
        var sel = cl
        var i = 2
        while (i <= cl && i < 6) {
            sel++
            i += 2
        }
        //Fix for pressing delete next to a forward slash
        if (clean == cleanC) sel--
        if (clean.length < 8) {
            clean += ddmmyyyy.substring(clean.length)
        } else {
            //This part makes sure that when we finish entering numbers
            //the date is correct, fixing it otherwise
            var day = clean.substring(0, 2).toInt()
            var mon = clean.substring(2, 4).toInt()
            var year = clean.substring(4, 8).toInt()
            mon = if (mon < 1) 1 else if (mon > 12) 12 else mon
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, mon - 1)
            year = if (year < 1900) 1900 else if (year > 2020) 2020 else year
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)

            day = if (day > cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE)) cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE) else day
            clean = String.format("%02d%02d%02d", day, mon, year)
        }
        clean = String.format("%s.%s.%s", clean.substring(0, 2),
                clean.substring(2, 4),
                clean.substring(4, 8))
        sel = if (sel < 0) 0 else sel
        current = clean
        input.setText(current)
        input.setSelection(if (sel < current.length) sel else current.length)

        saveDate(if (sel == 10) input.text.toString() else "")
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}

    init {
        input.addTextChangedListener(this)
    }
}
```

И осталось нам подключить его к нашему EditText

```
  DateInputMask(ac_registration_et_birth_date) { it ->
             //Ваша логика
            
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую дам обратную связь. А вместо «// ваша логика» что должно быть?

Comment: Вам же нужно дату получить))

Comment: ну как бы я ещё даже не junior, и мне многое не понятно ((

Comment: @jurvrn все это проходили)) Разобрались?

Comment: прочитал это developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/kotlin/class.php , но как ваш пример использовать не разобрался.